# Fourier transform on $\mathbb{Z}_{2}^{d}$

Tags: summation, fourier-series, inner-products, binary

Let $\mathbb{Z}_{2}^{d} = {\{\textbf{t} = (t_1, \ldots, t_d) : t_j \in \mathbb{Z}_2}\}$.

Define the inner product on functions $f, g : \mathbb{Z}_{2}^{d} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ to be:  $$\langle f, g \rangle = \sum_{\textbf{t} \in \mathbb{Z}_{2}^{d}} f(\textbf{t}) \overline{g(\textbf{t})}.$$

Let $f : \mathbb{Z}_{2}^{d} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. Define the fourier transform of $f$ at $\textbf{k} \in \ \mathbb{Z}_{2}^{d}$ to be: $$\widehat{f}(\textbf{k}) = \sum_{\textbf{t} \in \mathbb{Z}_{2}^{d}} f(\textbf{t})(-1)^{\textbf{k} \cdot \textbf{t}}$$ where $\textbf{k} \cdot \textbf{t} = k_1 t_1 + \ldots + k_d t_d$.

Now, I am trying to relate $\langle f,g \rangle$ and $\langle \widehat{f}, \widehat{g} \rangle$, where $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$ denotes the inner product of functions $f, g :  \mathbb{Z}_{2}^{d} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$.

I started with $$\langle \widehat{f}, \widehat{g} \rangle = \sum_{\textbf{t} \in \mathbb{Z}_{2}^{d}} \widehat{f}(\textbf{t}) \overline{\widehat{g(\textbf{t})}} = \sum_{\textbf{t} \in \mathbb{Z}_{2}^{d}} \sum_{\textbf{s} \in \mathbb{Z}_{2}^{d}}f(\textbf{s})(-1)^{\textbf{t} \cdot \textbf{s}} \sum_{\textbf{r} \in \mathbb{Z}_{2}^{d}}\overline{g(\textbf{r})}(-1)^{\textbf{t} \cdot \textbf{r}}$$ which after swapping summations, gives $$ \langle \widehat{f}, \widehat{g} \rangle = \sum_{\textbf{s} \in \mathbb{Z}_{2}^{d}} f(\textbf{s}) \sum_{\textbf{r} \in \mathbb{Z}_{2}^{d}}\overline{{g(\textbf{r})}} \sum_{\textbf{t} \in \mathbb{Z}_{2}^{d}}(-1)^{\textbf{t}\cdot(\textbf{s} + \textbf{r})}.$$ Now, when $\textbf{s} = \textbf{r}$, we get that $$\sum_{\textbf{t} \in \mathbb{Z}_{2}^{d}}(-1)^{\textbf{t}\cdot(\textbf{s} + \textbf{r})} = \sum_{\textbf{t} \in \mathbb{Z}_{2}^{d}}(-1)^{0} = \sum_{\textbf{t} \in \mathbb{Z}_{2}^{d}}1 = 2^d$$ and hence that $$\langle \widehat{f}, \widehat{g} \rangle =  2^d \langle f, g \rangle.$$

What about when $\textbf{s} \neq \textbf{r}$? What can be said about the sum $$\sum_{\textbf{t} \in \mathbb{Z}_{2}^{d}}(-1)^{\textbf{t}\cdot(\textbf{s} + \textbf{r})}$$ when $\textbf{s} \neq \textbf{r} \in \mathbb{Z}_{2}^{d}$?

Answer (score 1):

The last sum in your question is $0$, namely if $r, s \in \mathbb{Z}^d_2$ with $r\neq s$ then
$$
\tag{1} S:= \sum\limits_{t \in \mathbb{Z}_2^d } (-1)^{t\cdot (r+ s)} = 0.
$$
Indeed, assume there are exactly $1\leq k \leq d$ different bits in $s$ and $r$. WLOG, we may assume these $k$ bits are the first $k$, since otherwise we can simply rearrange the coordinates without changing the sum in $(1)$. Thus, $s_i \neq t_i$ for $i = 1,...,k$ and $s_i = t_i$ for $i = k+1,...,d$. We get $s_i + r_i = 1$ when $i = 1,...,k$ and $s_i + r_i \in \{0, 2\}$ for $i=k+1,...,d$, hence
$$
S = \sum\limits_{t\in \mathbb{Z}_2^d}(-1)^{ t_1 +...+t_k }.
$$
Now pair each $(t_1,...,t_k)\in \mathbb{Z}_2^k$ with $(1 - t_1,...,t_k)\in \mathbb{Z}_2^k$. Since both vectors are present in the sum for $S$ and have opposite signs, they cancel each other leaving $S = 0$.